# How to open Microsoft Edge in Internet Explorer(IE) Mode using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, headless

I have a webpage in which popup only opens in internet explorer and not in other browsers including chrome, fire fox and edge.
The only solution that I have to extract data from such pop up in headless mode is to load the page in edge in internet explorer mode. However I am not able to switch to internet explorer mode in edge using python. Is there any way this can be done? Image showing the settings that needed to be changed :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I understand that you want to launch the Edge browser with IE mode using **Selenium Python** code.

At present, we can only launch the Edge browser with IE mode using **Selenium C#** code.

If you are available to use selenium with C# language then you can refer to the steps below.

1. Download the latest version of IEDriverServer from the [Selenium site](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
2. Create a C# console project using Visual Studio.
3. Install **Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0** NuGet package from Nuget package manager.
4. Add the code below to the project and modify the paths.

---

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    var dir = "{FULL_PATH_TO_IEDRIVERSERVER}"; 
    var driver = "IEDriverServer.exe"; 
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir) || !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, driver))) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to find {0} in {1} folder.", dir, driver); 
        return; 
    } 

    var ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir, driver); 
    var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{}; 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", "{FULL_PATH_TO_MSEDGE.EXE}"); 

    var webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
    webdriver.Url = "http://Your_Site_URL_here..."; 
}
```

---

5. Run the project to test.

**Notes:**

1. Make sure to close all the Edge browser tabs and windows before running the code.
2. Use full paths in the code.

For example: `ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe");`.

Helpful references:

1. [Automating Internet Explorer mode](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/11/04/edge-chromium-release-candidate-get-ready/)
2. [webdriver-edge-ie-mode.cs](https://gist.github.com/kypflug/4e8291e6ee65929944f8ba74b1575dd8)

Comment: What if I want to use headless mode and open simultaneous browsers at once using multiprocessing,  how then will the code be altered? Can the code written in C# be integrated in a python script.

Comment: It looks like you are having a misunderstanding. IE browser does not support headless mode. Even if you try IE mode in the Edge browser, you cannot use the headless mode because IE mode uses the IE rendering engine. If you want to automate the IE mode using Selenium then you need to use C# language and you cannot integrate this code in Python script. The reason is some methods that are used in the C# code are not available in Python.